# How to float a div over Google Maps and keep it in fullscreen?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, responsive-design

I would like to put a div on a Google map, even when the map is in full screen.

I could already place the div in front of the map when it is not in full screen, but what I need is that the div is shown in both circumstances.

The div that i need to put over google map in fullscreen is: .cont-items-monitor

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="gx-card-body">
    <div class="cont-items-monitor overlay" style="display: none">
        <ul>
            <li>Seat León JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Seat Ibiza JMG-8823</li>
            <li>VW Vento JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Nissan Versa JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Nissan March JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Lincoln Navigator JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Seat León JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Seat Ibiza JMG-8823</li>
            <li>VW Vento JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Nissan Versa JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Nissan March JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Lincoln Navigator JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Seat León JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Seat Ibiza JMG-8823</li>
            <li>VW Vento JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Nissan Versa JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Nissan March JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Lincoln Navigator JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Seat León JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Seat Ibiza JMG-8823</li>
            <li>VW Vento JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Nissan Versa JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Nissan March JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Lincoln Navigator JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Seat León JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Seat Ibiza JMG-8823</li>
            <li>VW Vento JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Nissan Versa JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Nissan March JMG-8823</li>
            <li>Lincoln Navigator JMG-8823</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="google-map"></div>
</div>
```

My css code:

```
.cont-items-monitor {
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 0;
bottom: 30px;
z-index: 1;
background-color: white;
overflow-x: scroll;
padding: 10px 15px 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to give you a decent answer. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML element on top of full screen Google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644061/html-element-on-top-of-full-screen-google-map)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally could solve it.
What I had to do was put the div that I want to be superimposed on the first div that is generated when the Google map is initialized.

My html code is the same, the only thing I did was move it with jquery after all the elements of the website are loaded.

My html code super explained and verified:
(Imagine that the following code is inside the basic structure of an html page)

```
<div class="gx-card-body">
                                    <!-- <div class="cont-fab">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="gx-fab-btn gx-btn-primary">
                                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-add zmdi-hc-fw zmdi-hc-lg"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div> -->
                                    <div class="cont-items-monitor overlay" style="display: none">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Seat León JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Seat Ibiza JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>VW Vento JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Nissan Versa JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Nissan March JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Lincoln Navigator JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Seat León JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Seat Ibiza JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>VW Vento JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Nissan Versa JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Nissan March JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Lincoln Navigator JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Seat León JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Seat Ibiza JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>VW Vento JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Nissan Versa JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Nissan March JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Lincoln Navigator JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Seat León JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Seat Ibiza JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>VW Vento JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Nissan Versa JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Nissan March JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Lincoln Navigator JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Seat León JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Seat Ibiza JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>VW Vento JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Nissan Versa JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Nissan March JMG-8823</li>
                                            <li>Lincoln Navigator JMG-8823</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="google-map"></div>
                                </div>
```

My JS code (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cont-items-monitor').appendTo($('#google-map').find('div')[0]);
});
```

I hope it serves someone else

Comment: This worked smooth. I don't know why people have downvoted this question.