# Full Screen on Google Maps not showing search suggestions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not able to see Search suggestions in Full Screen when trying to search using the **Google maps** `places search box`. In normal mode, it's working fine, but if I toggle it to full-screen mode, the Search suggestions are missing. PFB screenshot for both the scenarios,

**Normal Mode**

[image: Normal Mode]

**Full Screen Mode**
[image: Full Screen Mode]

The code for the same could be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkumar091195/78nsv3p5/2/).

I found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644061/html-element-on-top-of-full-screen-google-map), in which a `custom element` is shown on the top of the map in Full-Screen mode using Javascript's `appendChild` method.

In my case, I am not able to find the selector for the suggestions list to be appended in **Google Map** `'map' div`. Please help me in how can I show the suggestions list in full-screen mode.

Comment: If the official Google Maps API examples show the same issue, you can consider this as a bug. Search for an existing issue in their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853) or open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to my own question, so that it may help anyone landing up here on the same issue.

I got a work-around solution for this issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56712072/4507489). The workaround is to

> move the `pac-container` `div`(suggestions list) inside the `map div`
> when entering the full screen, and move it back on exit.